# boost::geometry::within for a point in a geographic coordinate system fails --- why?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

Code:
I am using boost_1_61_0.  I am using the geometry part of the library for a GIS application.  The idea is to find points within defined regions (a rectangle in this case).  This works sometimes but not always.  Here is an example where the point should be within the rectangle but isn't...

I have the following test case:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/multi/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/geometry/io/wkt/wkt.hpp>

class wxPoint
{
public :
    double  getx() const
    {
        return m_x;
    }
    double gety() const
    {
        return m_y;
    }
    void setx( double in)
    {
        m_x = in;
    }
    void sety(double in)
    {
        m_y = in;
    }
private:
    double m_x;
    double m_y;
};

BOOST_GEOMETRY_REGISTER_POINT_2D_GET_SET(
    wxPoint,
    double,
    boost::geometry::cs::geographic<boost::geometry::degree>,
    wxPoint::getx,
    wxPoint::gety,
    wxPoint::setx,
    wxPoint::sety )

int main()
{
    boost::geometry::model::polygon< wxPoint > poly;

    boost::geometry::read_wkt( "POLYGON((0 89, 180 89, 180 0, 0 0, 0 89 ))", poly );  

    wxPoint point;
    point.setx( 150 );
    point.sety( 88 );

    bool within = boost::geometry::within( point, poly );


    return 0;
}
```

I expect `within` to be `true` but it is `false`.   Why is it `false`?

Comment: Just to note, if anyone thinks that perhaps the point with y at 88 is a bit extreme, it also fails at, say, y  = 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On further investigation, see my comments on the other answer, it appears that this is a difference in how boost geometry builds the polygon that you give it.

When we give a point as 0 0 to 180 0 this in boost land actually wraps the world to the west in this case and not the east as I and I'm sure you were expecting.

To prevent this from happening I would suggest inserting an extra point to break up any single vertex that has a longitude component greater than or equal to 180 degrees.  This forces boost to plot in the direction you intended rather than the shortest distance.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't put the points in clockwise order the `boost::geometry::within` may be undefined.

Try `boost::geometry::read_wkt( "POLYGON((0 89, 0 0, 180 0, 180 89, 0 89 ))", poly );`  instead

Comment: You're probably using a bottom left origin. Most computer graphics, boost included, start at the top left corner.

Comment: I've gone and fetch boost to have a try and changing the polygon to the one you suggested doesn't change it to work.  What is stranger is that using either direction does as soon as you get rid of 0 0 as a point in the polygon and replace it with 1 1.  It doesn't answer definitively who is right on the direction to use but I think it is pointing to a serious problem constructing a polygon using read_wrt or within() in general

Comment: In case it's of any further use I also tried constructing the poly in both directions using 'poly.outer().push_back(wxPoint(temp));' to push a set of points in and it makes no difference which implies an issue with the 'boost::geometry::within()' method.

Comment: I have also tried the two experiments that Saurbaum has done ---1) using the Polygon given by Ryan and 2) constructing the polygon without read_wkt() but using push_back().  within() still didn't work.